# PC display only shows distorted noise

Tags: windows-10

I was just facebooking and watching a youtube video, with Battle.net and Steam in the background, and suddenly, the display and the sound went off, and all I could see on my monitor was distorted noise, like on those old CRT TVs when there's no antenna.

The OS I was on is Windows 10, which just applied a system update
My processor is an AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor at 3.40 GHz
16GB RAM
64-bit OS
AMD Radeon RX 580 2048SP graphics card
AOC Monitor

What could have happened there? What should I check?

Comment: Did this persist after a reboot?

Comment: @harrymc it didn't occur again yet

Comment: Is the computer protected by Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS)?

Comment: @harrymc it isn't

Answer (score 0):

As this event only occurred, meaning was fixed by a reboot, and as the computer is
not protected by Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS), the most logical explanation
is a power surge that caused a malfunction.

Nevertheless, if this happens again without explanation, some check of the hardware
might be indicated.

If the electricity supply at your place is susceptible to surges, getting a UPS,
or at least a surge-protector, might be a good idea. Having protection against
power malfunction will also indicate, if the problem happens again,
that the cause is hardware rather than the power supply.